# Probability of two points being a certain distance apart on a circle

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Is the probability of two points being a certain distance $k$ apart on a circle of length $m$, with $0\le k<\frac{1}{2}m $, always the same for any $k$?

Comment: What is the "length" of a circle? How are you measuring the distance between the points (straight line, arc of the circle, or something else)? Are the distributions continuous, and if so, what do you mean by "the same" probability?

Comment: I'm measuring the arc length between the two points. And the length of the circle would be its circumference.

Comment: Is it possible for $k$ to be greater than $\frac12 m$? How?

Comment: That was a typo on my part (any k greater than $\frac{1}{2}$m could be mapped to something less than it) - I'll fix that.

Comment: Do you mean $0 < k < \frac{1}{2} m$? (the $k=0$ and $k=\frac{1}{2}m$ cases are equivalent I believe).

Comment: Would the 0 and $\frac{1}{2}$ cases be equal? One would result in the points having no distance between and the other being on opposite ends of a semicircle, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "yes," in the sense that if the two points were
determined by a probability distributed uniformly and independently (and continuously) along
the circumference, then the distance is a random real-valued variable uniformly distributed
over the interval $[0,\frac12 m].$

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "yes".

Probability that the distance is **exactly** $k$ is zero. But I guess your question was about probability of a distance to be "around" $k$, somewhere between $k$ and $k$ + $dx$. If $k$ is valid distance, this probability depends on $dx$ only, not on $k$ itself.

You choose the first point randomly, and after that suitable region for the second point consists of two arches, each having a length $dx$. Probability that the second point would get into this region is $2 * dx / m$. It does not depend on on position of the first point and does not depend on $k$.